# Use in-file Javascript with AngularJS and Apache Tiles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tiles, apache-tiles

I have been learning AngularJs and currently have an application that uses Apache Tiles. Prior to adding AngularJs to the application, I had a working piece of code inside my footer tile that calculated the current year that looks like this:

**footer.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    </script>

    <tr ng-Controller="AppController">
       <td>Created <script>document.write(year)</script>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

**controller.js**

```
    var controllers = {};
    controllers.AppController = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    }];
    proxy.controller(controllers);
```

**app.js**

```
     var proxy = angular.module('proxy',['ngRoute'])
           .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/index',{
                 templateUrl: 'search.jsp',
                 controller: 'AppController'
            });
     });
```

The footer now only shows "Created" on the index.html page. Is there a way with angular that I can successfully calculate the year? Why does the JS in this file stop working when AngularJs is added to the application?

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: @leo.fcx no, not for this page. I have a different error when I change views, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using AngularJS, you can write the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('app', []).controller('YearController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

        }]);
</script>

<table ng-app="app">
    <tr ng-controller="YearController">
        <td>
            Created {{currentYear}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: This is how it would look like if it was in it's own separate HTML and JavaScript files.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">  
    <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

footer.html:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-controller="YearController">
        <td>
            Created {{currentYear}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

app.js (better to have it's own separate file):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var controllers = {};
controllers.YearController = ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

}];
app.controller(controllers);
```

Comment: I tested your orginial code with AngularJS and it still worked, so I'm not completely sure what the issue may be.

Comment: I also got it to work when it was the same page. My footer.html does not declare 'ng-app' because tiles is inserting it. I have ng-app declared in my index.html. Would this make a difference when using angularjs in the footer.html?

Comment: I edited my answer to include more code. ng-app is now inside index.html. You can add a separate footer.html in a separate file and throw it into index.html using ng-include. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: For some reason it's still not working, but I feel like this should work. I went to the browser debug and it is getting a value for currentYear.

Comment: I edited the question to add my app.js and controller.js, since I had those already for the angular pieces and to update the footer.html to include your input.

Comment: Are you trying to do the old way or the new Angular way? If you're trying the new Angular way, footer.html has to be updated with Created {{currentYear}}.

Comment: I think the angular way might be better, but really any approach that works would be nice. I updated it in my project and forgot to change it here in the question, but it still hadn't worked.

Comment: So basically, I had a stupid moment, and had made a copy of the file in case things went wrong. I was editing the copy file and not the file that was being referenced in tiles. Thank you for the help.